# Drupal 7 - Using views to display KML of each node in respective maps for each node

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, openlayers, kml

I have been using Openlayers and geofield to try display the custom data layer (KML polygon) on the. First of all I havent been successful at it despite trying out many mays. Also I realized that the views approach discussed almost everywhere would show the custom maps on a 'new' Page or a 'new' block. But what I want is to show the map with the KML data layer right at each node.

Is this ever possible using Views (Data layer) + Openlayer + geofield in first case?

If so, how do I configure the geofield's map which is displayed in each node?

I have even asked the same question in Drupal forums, but haven't got any responses yet: http://drupal.org/node/1832006

Thanks a lot for any suggestions & help,

Raj Pawan G

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found this page to be very helpful for what you are trying to do:
http://www.syntux.nl/blog/basic-setup-drupal-7-openlayers-geofield-views-3.html